# Stop duplicate messages being posted from submit button

Tags: jquery

Hey basically just having a little trouble with the following, submitting a message from a textarea, and on clicking of the submit button the following runs... I need the button to be disabled or another way which stops the user from clicking the button several times and submitting the message over and over again. I think I know where I am going wrong below that it is disabling the button before it is submitting?. At the moment with the disabling code in, it disables the button but does not submit the message, if I remove it, it submits fine.

```
$("#leaguesubmit").click(function(){        
 if($('#messageinput').val().length > 300 || $('#messageinput').val().length == 0 || $('#messageinput').val() == "Please enter your league message here..." ){
    return false;

}else{
$("#leaguesubmit").attr("disabled","disabled");
return true;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right; once 'disabled' is set, the form won't submit. Try setting some other attribute when the form is submitted, and checking for it if the button is clicked again as part of the validation you're already doing:

```
$("#leaguesubmit").click(function() {        
  if($('#messageinput').val().length > 300 
     || $('#messageinput').val().length == 0
     || $('#messageinput').val() == "Please enter your league message here..."
     || $('#leaguesubmit').attr('submitted'))
  {
    return false;
  } else {
    $('#leaguesubmit').attr('submitted', true);
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: it was not working at first but then I realised you missed the # in the $('leaguesubmit').attr('submitted') haha. Thanks for your time!!.

Comment: ah, so I did! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Just check if btn is already pressed; like this:

```
var isSubmited = false;
$("#leaguesubmit").click(function(){        

if(isSubmited == true) return false;
isSubmited = true;

if($('#messageinput').val().length > 300 || $('#messageinput').val().length == 0 || $('#messageinput').val() == "Please enter your league message here..." ){
    isSubmited = false
    return false;

}else{
$("#leaguesubmit").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

isSubmited = false;
    return true;
    }
    });

Comment: This worked ok, but was error prone due to if the condition in the validation failed and it returned false, you are unable to submit anything unless you refresh the page due to the isSubmitted variable still being set to true. Thanks for your time anyway!.

Comment: Hey thanks yeah this works too, sorry I can only accept one! just the above answer is a bit more straight forward! and simpler for the same outcome. Thanks!.